# Regular expression for matching empty json values

Tags: php, json, ajax, regex, preg-replace

I have the next problem on PHP:

I need to get a JSON string with '[]' instead of empty values so I need a regular expresion for matching the empty values and changing them for '[]' with preg_replace.

An example of the json could be like this:

```
[{"id":"8176","token":"","name":null},...]
```

Im trying for so long with regular expressions but i cant find the correct one

the result should be like

```
[{"id":"8176","token":"[]","name":"[]"},...]
```

Comment: in php or in jQuery?

Comment: PHP, i just specified this, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Why would you use regular expressions to deal with JSON when PHP has `json_decode` ?

Comment: Because originally I have an array of php objects but i didnt get the clue to change empty values into '[]' so i thought that doing it with json would be easier, also i have to return a json

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/jzYyKE/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will replace `""` or `null` with `"[]"`.

```
$re = '/(\"\"|null)/';
$str = '[{"id":"8176","token":"","name":null},...]';
$subst = '\\"\\[\\]\\"';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

https://regex101.com/r/jzYyKE/1/

Or use str_replace:

```
$find = array('""', 'null');
$repl = '"[]"';
$str = '[{"id":"8176","token":"","name":null},...]';

$result = str_replace($find, $repl, $str);

echo $result;
```

https://3v4l.org/Oavhd